# WSSecurity - Accept UsernameToken header without timestamps or wsu:created

Tags: timestamp, ws-security, usernametoken

I am relatively new to Webservice Security and
I have a problem with security headers.

I want my security header to be accepted like this:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Without any timestamps or wsu:Created.

However I have not managed to achieve this.

When sending a request with this header
I always get a WSSecurityException telling me that the timestamp is missing.
When setting the "include timestamp in header" option to false I get a FailedAuthentication because the wsu:Created element is expected in the UsernameToken section.

What configuration is needed that the UsernameToken-section does not expect a Created part?

Is this even possible?

Thanks